# UWP XAMl ListView Item Template MVVM Events

Tags: xaml, uwp

If I want to implement the MVVM patern. What is the correct procedure for implementing a event such as DoubletTapped on TextBlock inside a Datatemplate of a ListView.ItemTemplate?

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate x:DataType="classes:Person">
         <TextBlock
            DoubleTapped="{x:Bind}"//what goes here to call a method on the ViewModel
            Foreground="Green"
            Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please modify your `TextBlock` Xaml as below:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="{x:Bind Name}" >
      <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DoubleTapped">
               <core:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding ElementName=RootPage, Path=DataContext.YourCommandMethod}"/>
          </core:EventTriggerBehavior>     
       </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
 </TextBlock>
```

`RootPage` is the name of Root Element, which in my case is a `Page`.